# How to grab list of tasks from a User using active record instead of an array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to grab the list of tasks that a user can do. I successfully was able to do that and here's my code

```
@tasklist = []     
user_info = [current_user.tag_list, current_user.ethnicity, current_user.gender, current_user.school, current_user.major ].flatten! 
          Task.all.each do |task|
            if task.tag_list.all? { |i| user_info.include?(i) }
            @tasklist.push(task)
            end
          end
```

Now, this is all great though in a prior implementation of my code. I had the @taglist as an active record and I used to use the two active record functions include and where on it as so:

```
@availabletasks = @tasklist.includes(:states).where(states: {user_id: current_user.id, value_cd: 0})
```

The ideal state is to replace my block of code that fetches the list of tasks to a single Query. 
The other option is to replace my second line of code by an array select statement. Though I have no clue how to do so.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what's on task and user `tag_list` associated to other table?

Comment: I can see that you tried to get all tasks belonging to current_user. Let's try this:
`current_user.tasks` so that you will get a list of tasks of current_user. But i'm not sure about `scholarship` variable. Where did you grant the value to this one?

Comment: I was wrong. A user has no relationship with Task. I am trying to match them using the tags_list where the user with this list of tags can do these tasks. The scholarship variable is a typo it should be actually a task I just fixed it